# When we start new activity into kotlin why we put .java in intent instead of .kt

Tags: android, kotlin

As per kotlin doc we start new activity with following syntax

**startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, NextActivity::class.java))**

its kotlin so why we add .java after the the class ? why not kt?

Comment: It's not a filename extension. It's a field in the Kotlin `KClass` object that gets you the Java `Class` object, as required by `startActivity()` method signature.

Comment: Because you are trying to get the `java.lang.Class` of the class, and not `KClass`

Comment: it means that  .kt has only syntax changes but in backgriund it uses JAVA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `NextActivity::class` gives you `KClass<NextActivity>`, and `KClass` has a method/extension property called [`java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) which gives you the `java.lang.Class<NextActivity>` for the given class.

You can even [check out the source-code for that `java` property.](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/3f71d364d55f5274a27fca7035441b701291c86d/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMapping.kt#L36-L40)

Comment: It's not really a "method", but a property.

Comment: It's called `getJavaClass()` in Java land, but yes, it *is* technically an `extension property`

Comment: it means that  .kt has only syntax changes but in backgriund it uses JAVA