# Android Kotlin parse Activity into fun

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I parse any activity into this `fun`

This code:

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + v?.tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    when (v?.tag) {
        "Account" -> start(AccountActivity::class)
    }
}

fun start(activity: Class<*>) {
    val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, activity)
    startActivity(i)
}
```

Gives an error on `start(AccountActivity::class)` stating `"Required Class<*>, found: KClass<AccountActivity>"`. But I don't want to ONLY be able to parse `AccountActivity`, any class extending `AppCompatActivity` should do.

#### Edit

The marked question is sort of an answer on my question but it is not my question.

Comment: You should create a function as `inline fun <reified T: Activity> Activity.startActivity() { startActivity(this, T::class.java) }` then call it as `startActivity<AccountActivity>()` thanks to Kotlin <3

Comment: Also I think you were originally looking for `fun <T: Activity> start(activity: Class<T>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652168/when-we-start-new-activity-into-kotlin-why-we-put-java-in-intent-instead-of-kt

Comment: Sorry @zsmb13 but you are probably blind? You mark my question as duplicate, but the actual QUESTION is NOT the same as the linked "duplicate" question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
start(AccountActivity::class.java)
```

You need to pass the Java `Class` instance, not Kotlin `KClass`.

Comment: Thanks, still learning Kotlin so things like these are new, I hope someone with the same question sees your answer.